# Stata: Esttab of xtreg with time fixed effects

Tags: stata

I'm trying to save output from several hundred `eststo`'s storing results of bivariate probability models into one excel file using esttab. It works for `xtlogit`(both `,re` and `,pa`), xtprobit (both `,re` and `,pa`) and for the linear probability model `xtreg` (both standard and `,fe`. However, when I use `xtreg y x i.year, fe` I get the error message `too many base levels specified`. Google doesn't help me much.

I've been trying for an hour to create a reproducible example but the stata datasets all work fine. It does not seem to be due to the number of years or the fact that different specifications have data for different years. Still, the normal `xtreg, fe'` works, the problem only appears with time dummies. The weirdest thing is that it works for *all* subsets of my variables but not for the whole list (again just the time fixed effects specifications).

Does anyone have an idea how to proceed? Using `drop(*.year)` works whenever the problem does *not* arise (so in specifications where it works, I get outputs without the year dummies) but does not prevent the `too many base levels specified` error; `,nobaselevels` has no apparent effect as well. Is there a way to remove the time fixed effects from `eststo` before I pass those on to `esttab`? Any workaround would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you might be facing is that of Stata creating different base levels for the factor variable `year`, in different regressions.

Try fixing the factor variable base level beforehand with `fvset`:

```
fvset base <some_number> year
```

Check `help fvset` and the manual entry for details. Also, read the source given below, which contains more information.

**Source:** two posts from Statalist; one from [Tim Wade](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2012-03/msg00840.html) and another by [Jeff Pitblado](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2010-12/msg00235.html).

Comment: yes, that helps, thanks! I'm sure I had tried that at some point... One does end up on the links you post via google... Anyways, now it runs! As an addon: in <some number>, you can specify the factor level, you don't have to specify a specific year.